# Get SQL result into variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is what I have so far. I want to store the query result into an int variable but I get null so far. After execute, both @query and @countrow are both null. Any suggestion would be great.

```
    SET @query = N'select @countrow=count(*) from ' + @tablename 
EXECUTE sp_executesql @query
```

Comment: If `@query` is null, then `@tablename` must be null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DECLARE @i INT, @sql NVARCHAR(512), @tablename varchar(200) = 'tbl'

SET @sql = N'SELECT @i = COUNT(*) FROM '  + @tablename

EXEC sp_executesql 
    @query = @sql, 
    @params = N'@i INT OUTPUT', 
    @i = @i OUTPUT 

PRINT @i
```

Take a look at [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bdd0a/3)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `OUTPUT` keyword, similar to this:

```
declare @query nvarchar(max)
declare  @countrow int
declare  @tablename varchar(50)

SET @query = N'select @cnt=count(*) from ' + @tablename 
EXECUTE sp_executesql @query, N'@cnt int OUTPUT', @cnt=@countrow OUTPUT

select @countrow as countrow -- to get the result
```